# Split pandas dataframe into multiple dataframes by looking for NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to split a dataframe from excel into multiple dataframes.

The dataframe looks like this:

|  | Name | Value | Unit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AA | 10 | mm |
| 1 | BDC | 20 | mm |
| 2 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | AFD | 60 | mm |
| 4 | AKW | 18 | cm |
| 5 | TDF | 0,5 | mm |
| 6 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 7 | AA | 10 | mm |
| 8 | FB | 65 | l |

I already got the whole dataframe in python stored correctly, however I have no clue how I can split the dataframe into multiple dataframes when there is a NaN row. I tried to iterate over .iterrows() but it only gives me the rows until the first NaN row. And what is the best practise to merge the rows into an new dataframe? Any help is appreciated.

```
content = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name='Parameter'))
right_tables = content[['Name', 'Value', 'Unit']]

for i, row in right_tables.head().iterrows():
    print(row)
```

Output in console:

```
Name      AA
Value     10
Unit      mm
Name: 0, dtype: object
Name     BDC
Value     20
Unit      mm
Name: 1, dtype: object
Name     NaN
Value    NaN
Unit     NaN
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

**And the result I need should be like:**
| | Name | Value | Unit |
|--|--|--|--|
|0|AA|10|mm|
|1|BDC|20|mm|

|  | Name | Value | Unit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AFD | 60 | mm |
| 1 | AKW | 18 | cm |
| 2 | TDF | 0,5 | mm |

|  | Name | Value | Unit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AA | 10 | mm |
| 1 | FB | 65 | l |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove missing rows by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and groupby by Series created by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) with [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
for g, df in df.dropna().groupby(df['Name'].isna().cumsum()):
    print (df.reset_index(drop=True))
  Name Value Unit
0   AA    10   mm
1  BDC    20   mm
  Name Value Unit
0  AFD    60   mm
1  AKW    18   cm
2  TDF   0,5   mm
  Name Value Unit
0   AA    10   mm
1   FB    65    l
```

If need list of DataFrames:

```
dfs= [df.reset_index(drop=True) for g,df in df.dropna().groupby(df['Name'].isna().cumsum())]
print (dfs)
[  Name Value Unit
0   AA    10   mm
1  BDC    20   mm,   Name Value Unit
0  AFD    60   mm
1  AKW    18   cm
2  TDF   0,5   mm,   Name Value Unit
0   AA    10   mm
1   FB    65    l]
```